# how to highlight json files as django templates in pycharm

Tags: json, django, pycharm

I am generating JSON files with django templates like so:

```
{
  "media_objects": [
    {% for media in media_list %}
        "{{ media.title }}"
        {% if not forloop.last %}
          ,
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  ]
}
```

This works fine, but I have trouble with syntax highlighting in Pycharm, because if Pycharm thinks this is JSON file it highlights it like so:
[image]

How do I add django template support for JSON files to enable auto-completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, the `my_file.json` file that you're about to create will not get populated with the Django Template Language (DTL) unless you handle it in a special way, there is a way to highlight/auto-complete DTL into JSON files in PyCharm.

1. Press `Ctrl + Alt + S` (equivalent to `File --> Settings`)
2. Go to `Languages & Frameworks`
3. Select `Python Template Languages`
4. Ensure that `Django`, at the top, is the selected Template Language
5. Click on the green `+` icon and select `JSON files`
6. Press `OK`